# Django-autocomplete-light returns object names instead of corresponding field values

Tags: python, django, django-autocomplete-light

My problem whith django-autocomplete-light (dal 3) is that in the admin, instead of showing the choices corresponding tom my designated field (i.e. `birth_nation` see `forms.py` section), I always get a list of the **str** values of my queryset objects (see #models.py section) which is actually the `last_name` field.

```
# models.py

class MyModel(models.Model):
   id_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
   middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   birth_city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
   birth_nation = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.last_name

   class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'mytable'

# forms.py
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    birth_nation = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=MyModel.objects.all(),
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='country-autocomplete',
                attrs={'data-minimum-input-length': 2}
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('__all__')


# views.py

class MyModelAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return MyModel.objects.none()

        qs = MyModel.objects.all()

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(birth_nation__istartswith=self.q)
        return qs
```

Obviously, I want to get my choices that correspond to the `birth_nation`, what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def __str__(self):
   return self.birth_nation
```

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete return value is a query object. If you want to see specific field in the object, write that field in your model class or change your autocomplete class return value.